# Why I should use pd.Index when I can use a list?

Tags: pandas

```
r = range(10)

ind1 = [*r]
ind2 = pd.Index([*r])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(r,index = ind1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(r,index = ind2)
```

Both ind1 and ind2 create the same dataframe.  So why do I need to use pd.Index ?  Any special reasons ?

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 |

Comment: Internally the list is converted into an index

Comment: So what's the purpose of pd.Index and why I need to use it ?

Comment: Is there somewhere in the docs where it stated that you have to use pd.Index? I'm not sure what the aim is here

Comment: I'm not saying that the doc says I must use.  But why create it when a list will do.  
If you know why there is a pd.Index when a list will do, I would like to listen.  And if there is no reason, why have a pd.Index. I also would like to know.  May be there is a difference, but no obvious.